# Open Source Alternative to ASP.NET membership

Tags: python, open-source, asp.net-membership, ldap, cherrypy

I'm currently supporting a Python web app with increasingly complicated user/role/permission management requirements.  Currently, we are rolling our own user, groups, permissions, etc. code and supporting database.

I'd like to find something like ASP.NET membership that can help manage user authentication and authorization, rather than risk security issues in continuing to create an increasingly complicated custom solution.  Are there any similar projects out there worth taking a look at?

Comment: What framework are you using for your web app?  Solutions depend on the framework (or the ability to inject appropriate WSGI middleware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for off site user authentication you might want to consider openid.  People have added [openid support to cherrypy](http://osdir.com/ml/python.cherrypy/2006-12/msg00074.html).

If you are looking for more user management type code.  I guess it depends on exactally what you are doing but others have done user management before, why not leverage off them.  [Skeletonz](http://orangoo.com/skeletonz/About/) is a CMS written on top of cherrypy.  If you are not wed to cherrypy you might also want to consider [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/).  It's built on Django with the idea of reusing work others have done so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: I agree that openid is probably the best option, unfortunately this system will be a closed one without Internet access. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Tony, where I work we are using ldap instead of a windows solution.  While ldap isn't simple it is common standard and is a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Paul. That's been my thinking as well, authenticating against an existing LDAP will probably be the approach we'll take for authentication.